# GMB MyBusiness API - How to set up real-time PubSub notifications?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-my-business-api

I am working on integrating GMB into some of our internal apps, and would like to set up to receive real-time notifications for reviews and questions.

I have created a topic, and a subscription with a valid URL.

The next step is to tell GMB to send the notifications to the topic, and I believe the endpoint is the one below. However, it is very vague about the parameters it wants.

This is the documentation 
https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts/updateNotifications

It wants a "Notification Settings Resource Name" in the URL, but it's not explained anywhere what that actually is. I have tried every possible value, but always get a 404 error response with the message "Requested entity was not found."

Has anyone successfully set this up? What values does the "getNotifications" endpoint want, and where in the various dashboards can this be found or created?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What are examples of values that you have tried? I would expect it to be of the form "projects/foo/topics/bar" if it is supposed to point to a specific Cloud resource. 
https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/admin#resource_names

Comment: There also seem to be more details in the documentation for the request message: https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/Notifications

Comment: The values I have tried are every string and name and ID number visible in this dashboard: https://console.cloud.google.com/projectselector2/cloudpubsub/topic/list

Comment: The value of form "projects/foo/topics/bar" I have as the "topicName" in the instance of "Notifications" in the request body. I reasonable positive that one is correct.
The one that nothing fits is the URL of form "https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/*/notifications"... It does not clearly explain anywhere that I can find what the * is supposed to be, beyond that it's a "Notification Settings Resource Name", which isn't terminology that is documented elsewhere.

Comment: I believe "accounts/${ACCOUNT_NAME}/notifications" is the notification settings resource name. Did you try replacing the  token in the middle with the name of the account resource?

Comment: I don't know what a "notification settings resource name" is. The documentation doesn't use this terminology elsewhere... That's my entire question....

Comment: My previous comment described what I think a "notification settings resource name" is.

Comment: I see, that may well be it - but it does not explain how to find or set this name.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to send the `accountId` as part of the URL.

To find this, you will first need to send a GET request to

`https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts`

This will return something along the following lines:

```
{
  "accounts": [
    {
      "name": "accounts/102647145453118950380",
      "accountName": "Tom Spencer",
      "type": "PERSONAL",
      "state": {
        "status": "UNVERIFIED",
        "vettedStatus": "NOT_VETTED"
      },
      "profilePhotoUrl": "//lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GgPkuJj03DeCa1isBAJALY4eOl09WGYVFrM4mG5=s132"
    },
  ]
}
```

You can see here that `accounts/102647145453118950380` is returned in the `name` field. Take this field, and construct the following URL:

`https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/102647145453118950380/notifications`

Send a PUT request to this URL, with a request body resembling the following:

```
{
  "topicName": "projects/{projectId}/topics/{topicId}",
  "notificationTypes": [
    "NEW_REVIEW",
    "UPDATED_REVIEW"
  ]
}
```

Assuming you have pub/sub setup [as per the documentation](https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/notification-setup), this should send a message to your topic/subscribers whenever a new review is created or a review is updated.